# Why is my Facebook Pixel firing the purchase event erroneously on Shopify?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, shopify, shopify-api

Rarely, my Facebook Pixel will fire a purchase on the product pages rather than the checkout page. The site is using the standard Facebook + Shopify integration.

[Facebook events manager showing purchase events](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3e2Ve.jpg)

It always includes a value and currency parameter but will occasionally pass more parameters. I can't find anywhere in the code where this is being called, and I haven't been able to recreate it myself.

Comment: This integration is broken. I've been seeing this issue all over.